# Upper bound for $\exp(\exp(iz))$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $|z| > 1, \arg z \in [0, \pi]$.

Show that $e^{e^{iz}} \leq 1$

I tried few approaches but they led me nowhere.

Comment: Why would it even be *real*? Counterexamples: for $z=2i$, the result is real but $>1$. For $z=3/2$ the result is complex.

Comment: The inequality $|e^{e^{iz}}| \leq 1$ is also false under the given hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to show that $|e^{e^{iz}}| \leq 1.$ But this is not true (see the comment of Jean Claude Arbaut).

We have that for all $w \in \mathbb C:$

$$ (*) \quad |e^w| \le e^{|w|}.$$

Now let $z=x+iy \in \mathbb C$ with $\arg z \in [0, \pi]$, then $y \ge 0.$ Thus $iz=ix-y.$ Therefore $w:=e^{iz}= e^{ix}e^{-y}$. This gives $|w|=e^{-y} \le 1.$

From $(*)$ we now derive

$$|e^{e^{iz}}|= |e^w| \le e^{|w|} \le e^1=e.$$

Comment: I think we can do slightly better since $x^2+y^2$ must be greater that $1$. The bound seems to be less that $e-1$.

Comment: Or rather $e^{\cos 1}\simeq1.71653$.